# How to calculate P(E) here.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

So, I had a probability question in precalculus. So, I did all the work and found out that the  sample space is $[0,5]$ on the x axis and y axis (question involves 2 random numbers). Then I found out that the event space (E) is all solutions in the sample space that can satisfy                   $3.5≤x+y<4.5$. I graphed it out and I found the event space. I just need to calculate the area of that event space so I can put it over 25 (sample space area) to find P(E). P(E) is just (area of event space)/25. So if someone can show me how to calculate the event space in this case it would be very helpful.

Comment: Integral of the area under x+y=4.5 minus the integral of the area under x+y=3.5, if you are going to integrate using the x variable than use 'dx' and x from 0 to 5 on both integrals. This gives you the area representing P(E), then divvide by $5 \cdot 5 = 25$.

Comment: The easiest way is to draw a picture.  You will see that the complement of $E$ is two triangles, whose area can be easily calculated.

Comment: I don't know integrals yet, that is later in the year. I looked at the graph and I had trouble finding the area of the figure. It looks like a trapezoid and I was going to use the formula but I don't know the height.

Answer (score 1):

You have not described the original problem. We assume your analysis is correct.

Consider first the part of our $5\times 5$ square that is below the line $x+y=4.5$. This is a right-angled isosceles triangle with legs of length $4.5$. So it has area $\frac{1}{2}(4.5)^2$.

Now **subtract** the area of the part of the square that is below the line $x+y=3.5$. This region has area $\frac{1}{2}(3.5)^2$. So our desired area is
$$\frac{1}{2}(4.5)^2-\frac{1}{2}(3.5)^2.$$
This simplifies to $4$.